# The google translator icon disappears from my address bar when I load my website

Tags: html, google-translator-toolkit

I need to be able to translate my web application into another language. I enabled the google translate extension in chrome. When I load my company website with chrome the translate icon appears and I can translate the site. I then loaded my secure web application in chrome and the translate icon disappeared. My knowledge on how the translator works with web pages in minimal at best. Any help would be appreciated as I do not know where to begin. Any links to helpful articles on how the translator does its job would also be appreciated

Comment: It might be useful to provide the link to the chrome extension you're using. If you're using the built-in translation capabilities of chrome, you might want to consult https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with the google translate (gt) icon disappearing from the right side of the Chrome address bar. I believe I caused the problem myself as I was trying to come up with a way to use it to switch languages quickly using *Keyboard Maestro*.

I keep 2 Chrome windows open with 2 different gmail accounts, and the gt icon was only missing from one of the windows. I tried many things and couldn't get the gt icon to come back.

Eventually, I was able to fix the problem based on the procedure described on this [page](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/64344427/set-translate-icon-as-default-in-chrome-search-bar?hl=en&msgid=64514008), which suggests going to this address: [chrome://settings/languages](http://chrome://settings/languages) to make sure the *Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language you read* option is on in the Languages section, as shown in this image:
[image: dialog for language setting]

In my case, the option was already set to on. So I turned it off, logged out of the account associated with that Chrome window, closed that browser window, and when I opened a fresh browser window for that gmail account the gt icon was back.

I'm using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.93 on a MacAir (M1, 2020) running MacOS 12.0.1